# Bitwise operations in Java give different value with similar code?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Short question. I am quite new to doing bit/bytewise operations in Java, but I noticed something strange.

The code below gives as output:

```
2
0
```

code:

```
String[] nodes = new String[3];
boolean in;
int index = 0;
int hash = "hi".hashCode();
in = (nodes[(index = nodes.length - 1) & hash]) != null;
System.out.println(index);
index = (nodes.length - 1) & hash;
System.out.println(index);
```

Why is it, that index has a different value even though the operation to assign a value to index is identical in the 5th and 7th line of code?

Like I said, I'm new to bitwise/bytewise operations so I'm probably missing some background information.

Comment: I have no idea what that code is supposed to do or demonstrate. You're wrong about the assignments being identical though, so...

Comment: First time you do `index = nodes.length - 1`, second time you do `index = (nodes.length - 1) & hash`, so why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: On the first print, `index = nodes.length - 1`.  On the second, `index = (nodes.length - 1) & hash;`.  Note that you are ignoring `in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(index = nodes.length - 1) & hash
```

assigns `nodes.length - 1` to `index`, then bitwise-ands it with `hash`.

```
index = (nodes.length - 1) & hash
```

bitwise-ands `nodes.length - 1` with `hash`, then assigns the result to `index`.

Not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your first assigment to `index` happens in the parenthesis here:

```
in = (nodes[(index = nodes.length - 1) & hash]) != null;
```

Which is

```
index = nodes.length - 1
```

and has a value of "two". Your second assignment (`index = (nodes.length - 1) & hash;`) differs; you added a `& hash` which presumably has the two bit as `0` thus when you perform the bitwise `&` it becomes `0`.